# My php form is not passing data since I have implemented auto suggest

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, autosuggest

Here is my scenario, All things were working fine ,based on what  I enter in the search form the appropriate image was displayed. But since I have added that auto suggest feature on my site, it seems like whatever I write in search box and presses search, I think my input form is not sending data to php. beacuse even if I type something in form, Still this condition is getting false.
( $name contains the value user inputs):

```
if(!empty($name))
```

Here is my html form:

```
<form class="searchform" action="webpage.php" method="POST">
<input class="searchfield autosuggest" type="text"  placeholder="Search for a name " onFocus="if (this.value == 'Search...') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search...';}" />
<input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

The latest script I added for auto suggest is this :

```
  //Autosuggest starts here


$(document).ready(function(){
$('.autosuggest').keyup(function(){


var search_term= $(this).attr('value');
$.post('search.php',{search_term:search_term},function(data){

    $('.results').html(data);

    $('.results li').click(function(){
        var result_value = $(this).text();
        $('.autosuggest').attr('value',result_value);
        $('.results').html('');
    });

});

});
});

</script>
```

Finally this is another search.php file for querying through the database for autosuggest :

```
if(isset($_POST['search_term'])== true && empty($_POST['search_term'])== false)
{
    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_term']);
    $query = mysql_query("select * from user_info where Name LIKE '$search_term%'");

    while(($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))!== false)
    {
    echo '<li>'.$rows['Name'].'</li>';
    }
}
```

Now the auto suggest is working but not the main site. Could it be a positioning issue of my image or  php not receiving data from my input form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add name attribute to your input box

Comment: Oh Thanks alot , I added the name attribute to both the input and submit form. and got it working. Can u explain why the name attribute is always required ?

Comment: so you can control the data passed

Comment: I must say Stackoverflow & the people are here are great for helping others. I have always got quick & positive response here. May God bless you all 1!!

Comment: I am trying to do one more thing. You have seen my code above, what if I want to pass the data to php when the user clicks on the anyone of the list in dropdown. Right now if user clicks on some name in list, that name goes into the field and to pass the data user has to press the search button. Can I do the both actions just by clicking ? How?

Comment: Just simply ask a new question. ^^

Comment: Its simple , just need to add submit() function in the onclick event.